# Set clock in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to set current date in Ubuntu 22.04 using:

```
date -s YY/MM/DD
```

but I am getting error:

```
date: invalid date ‘YY/MM/DD’
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question seems to have been answered on other sites of the Stack Exchange network
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151548/17649

Comment: What did you think that would set it to?

Answer (score 1):

you don't seem to be setting in values, rather you're passing in the format

perhaps try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679988/how-to-change-ubuntus-server-date-and-time-via-command-line) solution:

```
sudo date --set="2015-09-30 10:05:59.990"
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to change the systemtime?

then you need to use timedatectl.

for example:

```
sudo timedatectl set-time "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"
```

you can check if it worked by

```
timedatectl
```

Comment: does it work if ntp is enabled?

Comment: yes it does but NTP will overwrite/correct back to the time coming from the server. if you want to adjust the system time you may check if you get the right time from the NTP-Server. The NTP configuration file is located at /etc/ntp.conf. You can use a text editor to edit this file. The configuration file allows you to specify NTP servers from which your system will synchronize its time. Example configuration using default Ubuntu NTP servers: server ntp.ubuntu.com